# How can I save an image to a temporary file to use later?

Tags: css, casperjs

Here is my simple script to see if the image exists. Is there is any way I can save the image using the selector to see if it exists? This is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://example.ws/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('https://example.ws/login.html', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
        if (this.exists('img#cpt_img')) {
        this.echo('the heading exists');
        }
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the download() method:

```
this.download(
    this.getElementAttribute('img#cpt_img', 'src'),
    "my_image.png"
);
```